# CSS & JavaScript Popup Not Working

Tags: javascript

Why isn't this JavaScript function triggering the popup? I've tried .classlist as well as style.visibility and neither triggers the #filter div to display.

```
<div class='lpicon' onclick="designFunction">
    <img class='lpactionicon'  src='file:///Users/homefolder/Desktop/Hyperspace%20Website/Images/Launchpad/LP%20Action%20Icon-%20Design.png'/>
</div>

<div id='filter'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lpicon {
   height: 100px;
   width: 50px;
   margin-left: 14%;
   margin-top: 8%;
   float: left;   }

#filter {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .7;
  top: 0px; }
```

JavaScript:

```
function designFunction() {
     document.getElementById("filter").classList.remove("block");
 }
```

Comment: You need to execute your function add this after your function `designFunction();`

Comment: Doesn't look like `#filter` has a class of `block` to remove ?

Comment: `designFunction()` needs to be defined in the global/window scope, see example: https://jsfiddle.net/k7yvo7xu/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use designFunction() and  you need to change the CSS of The filter div so you are using block if not then you have to provide more code because block is present no where. You can set that by slecting it and using `.CSS()` for making it visible. See its documentation for more info.

Comment: For changing CSS in javascrit you can use ```document.getElementById("filter").style.display="block"  ```